# Assigning char [][] to char**

Tags: c++, arrays

I am working on an assignment where we are given a two dimensional array we need to do some calculations with.

I wanted to encapsulate the logic of the calculations into it's own class so in my calculations class I have member char** that I am trying to initialize with the given char arr[5][5]. I first tried to do a c-style cast, which got it to compile, but results in a segfault if I try to deference my member variable.

In short, why does this not work

```
 class MyClass{
      Myclass(char arr[5][5]){
        m_PmyArr = arr; //doesn't work
     }
     char** m_PmyArr;
 };
```

And why does this compile, but result in segfault upon dereference

```
class MyClass{
     Myclass(char arr[5][5]){
        m_PmyArr = (char**)arr; //will compile, but will segfault
     }
     char** m_PmyArr;
 };
```

I hope this is not interpreted as "Do my work for me", I have genuinely been trying to get a better grasp on the nuances of pointers and this is contrary to how I previously understood the relationship between arrays and pointers

Comment: Reminder:  The assignment operator is copying *pointers* and not the contents of the matrix.

Answer (score 5):

A `int[5][5]` is not the same as a `int**`.  While an array can decay into a pointer when passed to a function, this doesn't happen at multiple array levels.  So the two cannot be converted.

Even if you made the pointers compatible, you would need to consider the source of the pointer.  If it came from a local variable, and the object outlives the function it was created in, the pointer would become invalid.

You should allocate the memory dynamically instead:

```
 class MyClass{
      Myclass(int rows, int cols){
        int i;
        this->rows = rows;
        this->cols = cols;
        m_PmyArr = new int*[rows];
        for (i=0; i<rows; i++) {
            m_PmyArr[i] = new int[cols];
        }
     }
     ~Myclass() {
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<rows; i++) {
            delete[] m_PmyArr[i];
        }
        delete[] m_PmyArr;
     }
     char** m_PmyArr;
     int rows, cols;
 };
```

Answer (score 4):

Once you get passed single-indirection pointers, I find it helps to start thinking conceptually about what these constructs mean. Here's a picture illustrating the difference between `char**`, which points to `char*`... and what `char[5][5]` looks like.

[image]

The two are not interchangable. With a `char[5][5]`, you can't take a pointer to a pointer to `char`... because each "element" isn't a `char*`, it's a `char[5]`... you need a pointer to *that*.

Answer (score 3):

`m_PmyArr` is of type `char**` while in the statement `m_PmyArr = arr`, `arr` (after decay) is of type `char (*)[5]`. Both `m_PmyArr` and `arr` are of incompatible type.
Casting `arr` to `char**` only shuts down the compiler warning ignoring any erroneous behavior of the program.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays and pointers are difficult to handle, which is why you normally just use `std::vector`, `std::string` et al.

Let's have a look at your constructor:

> ```
> Myclass(char arr[5][5])
> ```

This does not mean what you think it means. Arrays cannot be passed by value; it is said that an array "decays" to a pointer to its first element. This is exactly what happens here.

Your constructor is equivalent to the following syntactical monstrosity:

```
Myclass(char(*arr)[5])
```

*(You can easily verify this by adding it to your class. Your compiler should complain about a redefinition.)*

How comes? Consider this: a two-dimensional array is really a one-dimensional array, just that its element type is somewhat special. Just like an array `int arr[5]` consists of 5 `int` elements, an array `char arr[5][5]` consists of 5 `char[5]` elements. From this observation, we can conclude that **`char[5]` is a type**.

In other words, what your constructor really receives is a pointer to the first element of an array in which every element is a `char[5]`.

> ```
> m_PmyArr = arr; //doesn't work
> ```

Yes, because the elements of `m_PmyArr` are of type `char*` and not of `char[5]`. The compiler prevents you from assigning pointers to incompatible types.

> And why does this compile, but result in segfault upon dereference
>
> [...]
>
> ```
>     m_PmyArr = (char**)arr; //will compile, but will segfault
> ```

Because the C-style cast disables the compiler's error-checking tools.

Formally, in your real code you are probably hit by undefined behaviour, which probably results in a crash because a `char*` probably needs less (or more) space in memory on your machine than a `char[5]`, so your program probably has some some memory issues. That's a lot of "probably"s there, but such is the nature of undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyClass{
      Myclass(char arr[5][5]){
        m_PmyArr = arr; //doesn't work
     }
     char** m_PmyArr;
 };
```

is not right since `arr` decays to `char (*)[5]`, not to `char**`.

```
class MyClass{
     Myclass(char arr[5][5]){
        m_PmyArr = (char**)arr; //will compile, but will segfault
     }
     char** m_PmyArr;
 };
```

will compile but will cause problems later on depending on how you use the member variable and what was used to construct an object, as you already noticed.

You could use something like:

```
class MyClass{
      Myclass(char (&arr)[5][5]){
         memcpy(m_PmyArr, arr, sizeof(m_PmyArr));
     }
     char m_PmyArr[5][5];
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

The types are not compatible.  A two-dimensional array is really the juxtaposition of one-dimensional arrays, analogous to the juxtaposition of single elements in a one-dimensional array.

You should consider using `std::vector`.  However, if you want -- or have -- to stick to simulating two-dimensional arrays through pointers, you might try to use templates.

```
class C {
    private:
        size_t rows, cols;
        int **matrix;

    public:
        template <size_t NR, size_t NC> C(const int (&m)[NR][NC]) :
            rows(NR), cols(NC), matrix(new int *[NR])
        {
            for(size_t r=0; r<rows; ++r){
                matrix[r]=new int[cols];
                std::copy(m[r], m[r]+cols, matrix[r]);
            }
        }

        ~C(){
            for(size_t r=0; r<rows; r++)
                delete[] matrix[r];
            delete[] matrix;
        }
};
```

Comment: +1 for *"A two-dimensional array is really the juxtaposition of one-dimensional array, analogous to the juxtaposition of single elements in a one-dimensional array."*

Answer (score 0):

char** is just a pointer-to-pointer-to-char. In order for it to represent a 2d array, it has to point to a list of pointers, which in turn point to the rows. Other answers show this. You have to do the pointer arithmetic manually.

With char [5][5], the compiler can work out the memory required and the pointer arithmetic to dereference at a given index. That's why it's a different type. char [][5] can be used as a function argument type. It tells the compiler that there are 5 chars in a row, so it knows where in the block of memory one row ends another starts.

Answer (score 0):

If the array size is known at compile time you could use template function to figure out the array dimensions and process the data from the array:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int w, int h>
void f(int(&a)[w][h])
{
    std::cout << "Width: " << w << " Height: " << h << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int a1[2][3];
    int a2[4][5];

    f(a1);
    f(a2);
}
```

That, of course, will not work if you want to allocate memory dynamically (e.g. ask user for dimensions).